# Problems with installing jsdom through npm on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: jquery, linux, node.js, ubuntu, jsdom

I've tried to install jsdom for use in a script I'm using, however, I constantly run into an error and cannot seem to find a solution anywhere for it. Most people have problems of not having g++ installed, which I do have installed.

Anyways, this is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "learning_nodejs",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "script.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "optimist": "~0.6.1",
    "jquery": "~2.1.3",
    "jsdom": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause"
}
```

I then delete the node_modules file if it's there from a previous attempt. Go to the directory of package.json and run `npm install`

This seems to work for a bit, but then I run into a bunch of errors. This should be enough to tell what is going on:

```
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: UNKNOWN, unlink '/home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/cssstyle/lib/properties.js'
npm ERR! error rolling back  jsdom@4.0.4 { [Error: UNKNOWN, unlink '/home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/cssstyle/lib/properties.js']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -1,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'UNKNOWN',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/cssstyle/lib/properties.js' }
npm ERR! Error: EROFS, symlink '../acorn/bin/acorn'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path ../acorn/bin/acorn
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! errno 56
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/parse5/lib/tree_construction/doctype.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/parse5/lib/tree_construction/doctype.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/parse5/lib/tree_construction/doctype.js
```

...

```
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/combined-stream/node_modules/delayed-stream/test
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/combined-stream/node_modules/delayed-stream/test/common.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call setupMadeDir
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack end (/usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:319:21)
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:336:20
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:358:20
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing source-map@0.1.43
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/daniel/Desktop/virtual_share/javascript_stuff/learning_nodejs/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Anyways I have a feeling this has to do with the fact that my projected is on a mounted shared drive between Ubuntu 14.04 (virtualized) and my host os.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution!

[This page is very helpful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269727/npm-errors-when-installing-packages-on-windows-share)

Basically, this was indeed because of the shared file, but just adding --no-bin-links fixes it. Hopefully this helps someone!